# setState not able to set the value of array

Tags: reactjs

Not Able to alter the table after delete button is Clicked value are passed correctly but not able to set the state. The state gets altered in the second in console.log but still all the data's are being displayed.

```
class ShoppingList extends Component{
    state = {
        items: [
            {id: uuid(), name:'Eggs'},
            {id: uuid(), name:'Milk'},
            {id: uuid(), name:'Water'},
            {id: uuid(), name:'Tea'}
        ]

    }
```

// render Method starts here.

```
 render() {
        const {items} = this.state

        return(
            <div>
                <Container>
                <Button color="dark" style={{marginBottom:'2rem'}} onClick={() => {
                    const name = prompt('Enter Item');
                    if(name){
                        console.log('Entered')
                        this.setState(state =>({items:[...state.items, {id:uuid(), name}]}));

                    }
                }}>Add Item</Button>
                <ListGroup>
                    <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                    {items.map(({id, name}) => (
                         <ListGroupItem>
                             <Button className="remove-button" color="danger" size="sm"
                             onClick={() => {const arrayCopy = this.state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
                                 console.log(arrayCopy)
                                    this.setState({items: arrayCopy});
enter code here
                                 debugger;
                                 console.log('Check',items)
                                 console.log('Check',arrayCopy)
                             }}>&times;</Button>
                             {name}
                         </ListGroupItem>
                    ))}
                    </TransitionGroup>``
                </ListGroup>
                </Container>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these `console.log()` inside a callback function. Because, `this.setState()` is an async function. Then you will not get the right value when console log like that.

```
this.setState({items: arrayCopy}, () => {
  // Do what you need in this callback function
  console.log('Check',items)
  console.log('Check',arrayCopy)
});
```

Comment: The format of writing the console log is really good. i learned something new but that is not the solution i was looking for.

Comment: im not able to map the deleted data, "arrayCopy" is receiving 1 less "data" but it is not getting deleted in the "mapped data"

Comment: Maybe its an issue regarding reactstrap that i'm using in these codes. i replace it with simple html tags. Tnx bro your the man.. :)